# Linking of Specific excel columns via Open Xml

Tags: c#, openxml

using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` i am able to get specific row and specific columns data from excel sheet in to a list by using below code

```
Excel.Workbook MyWorkBook = Excel_App.Workbooks.Open(path, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
Excel.Worksheet MyWorksheet = null;
MyWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)MyWorkBook.Sheets[(1)];
Excel.Range Excel_Range;
Excel_Range = MyWorksheet.UsedRange;
SheetCount = MyWorkBook.Sheets.Count;
Lastrow = MyWorksheet.Cells.Find("*", System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value).Row;
LastColumn = MyWorksheet.Cells.Find("*", System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value).Column;

for (int i = 8; i <= Lastrow; i++)
{


        List_MAPPING_FILE_A429_PATHS.Add((string)(Excel_Range.Cells[i, 4] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString());
        List_MAPPING_FILE_ASCB_PATHS.Add((string)(Excel_Range.Cells[i, 5] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString());

}
```

now i want to get same data stored in list by using OpenXml.dll  i tried below code but got stuck how to proceed further

```
public void AddtoLogFile( )
{
    string temp =@"C:\Ported\DATA\EJETE2_A429RX_TIF_temp.xml";
    using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(temp, true))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = myDoc.WorkbookPart;
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
        SheetData sheetData =
        worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
        foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
        {
            foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
            {
                string text = c.CellValue.Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

can someone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

The Cells location is stored in Cell.CellReference,

The cells reference for the first cell would be "A1"

Use this method to extract the Column:

```
private static readonly Regex ColumnNameRegex = new Regex("[A-Za-z]+");  
private static string GetColumnName(string cellReference)
    {
        if (ColumnNameRegex.IsMatch(cellReference))
            return ColumnNameRegex.Match(cellReference).Value;

        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(cellReference);
    }
```

Not sure what your trying to get from the Spreadsheet, I guess you only want the information from cells in the certain row:

```
 foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
    {
        foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
        {
            if (GetColumnName(c.CellReference) == "A")
            {
            string text = c.CellValue.InnerText;
            }
        }
    }
```

The data given from CellVaule.InnerText will be a reference to the SharedStringTabl which holds all the strings for a worksheet. You will need to get the data from the SharedStringTable which is stored as

WorkBookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable;

For this I use a method that takes the Cell and SharedStringTable to return the value:

```
        public static string GetCellV (Cell cell, SharedStringTable ss)
    {
        string cellV = null;

        try
        {
            cellV = cell.CellValue.InnerText;
            if (cell.DataType != null
              && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
            {
                cellV = ss.ElementAt(Int32.Parse(cellV)).InnerText;
            }
            else
            {
                cellV = cell.CellValue.InnerText;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            cellV = " ";
        }

        return cellV;
    }
```